# Transform List of Tuple Lists into single list of tuples

Tags: f#

I have a large list that looks essentially like this:

let someList = [ [(1,2);(2,3);etc]; [(1,2);(2,3);etc]; etc]

a list that contains lists, that contain tuples. what is the best way to reduce that into a single list of all the tuples?

Comment: Note: This should be independent of the contents of the lists.

Comment: yeah, the fact that the inner lists contains tuples is irrelevant. the inner lists could contain any data type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a built-in function for this, [List.concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370370.aspx)

```
[[(1,2); (3,4)]; [(5,6); (7,8)] ] |> List.concat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let l = [[(1,2); (3,4)]; [(5,6); (7,8)] ]
let flattened = List.collect id l // [(1, 2); (3, 4); (5, 6); (7, 8)]
```

Comment: that does the trick, can you please explain what it means? i'm just learning F#, thanks.

Comment: the List.collect id part i mean

Comment: he's applying the id function to each element, and concatenating the results. I guess it's the equivalent of SelectMany in Linq.